# How to make this search bar responsive in Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am looking for a way to make this search bar with its inputs and buttons responsive. However i got stuck with Bootstrap properties and when I shrink the window everything stacks very bad and I just can't figure out how to apply some better classes and props. Here's the codepen link: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WGKOmB

Appreciate all advices

This is my html:

```css
.row {
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 40px 30px;
}
.main {
  background-color: grey;
  width: 1202px;
  height: 156px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.formContainer {
  width: 1140px;
  height: 85px;
  background-color: green;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
}
button {
  height: 37px;
  width: 160px;
}
.choice {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  height: 37px;
}
div.form-group.checkbox {
  width: 207px;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
select.form-control {
  width: 173px;
}
input.form-control.choice-input {
  /*.choice input input*/
  width: 360px;
  height: 38px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <!-- row -->

      <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-6" style="background-color: lightblue; height: 74px;">
        <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
        <div class="form-inline">
          <div class="form-group checkbox">
            <span><input type="checkbox" value="" checked></span>
            <label>Lorem</label>
            <span><input type="checkbox" value=""></span>
            <label>Ipsum</label>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control">
              <option value="one">Lorem ipsum</option>
              <option value="two">Two</option>
              <option value="three">Three</option>
              <option value="four">Four</option>
              <option value="five">Five</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control choice-input" type="text" placeholder="Placeholder text">
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- end form-inline -->
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6" style="background-color: lightgreen; height: 74px;">

        <p class="pull-right">Lorem ipsum</p>
        <div class="btn-group">
          <button class="btn btn-default" style="margin-right: 10px">Lorem ipsum lorem</button>
          <button class="btn btn-default">Lorem lorem lorem</button>
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- end row -->
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: You could use media queries to achive what you want.

In your Css: 
\@media (width: 60em) { /* Breite entspricht genau 60em */ }
\@media (min-width: 50em) { /* Breite beträgt mindestens 50em */ }
\@media (max-width: 70em) { /* Breite beträgt höchstens 70em */ }

I would also recommend to NOT overwrite twitters bootstrap classes (like you did with your ".row" padding settings).
In general: Stop mixin inline styles and classes. Thats very confusing.

What do you want to achive, maybe we can help if you describe a bit more....

Comment: Sorry I don't understand properties in German..what I would like to achieve is to make each element (checkboxes, select box, input field and buttons) stack under one another when the window is resized

Answer (score 0):

Word from the wise (not me), never use inline styling. Always put everything in CSS. Also, you set a specific height for both the blue box and the light green box. Therefore, even when the browser is narrower and would be in col-sm-* and col-xs-* territory, you still have a set height. You should give a class name, for example form-height and then in CSS write something like the following:

```
.form-height {
    height: 150px; /* Or whatever height you find appropriate */
}
@media (min-width:768px) {
    .form-height {
        height: 74px;
    }
}
```

What this would do is say that when the browser is narrower than 768px, i.e. when it is considered col-xs-* by bootstrap, it should have a certain height. When it is larger it will have a different height.

However, an ever better solution is to never even use the height property. The reason you are doing this is probably because you want a certain padding. Therefore, you can write the following CSS for the class:

```
.form-height {
    padding: 10px 0px; /* Give the top and bottom 10px of padding and nothing to the right or left */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<div class="container">
<form class="form-inline" style="padding: 20px 0;">
    <div class="row">   
        <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-9">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" value="">Option 1</label>
                <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" value="">Option 2</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
                    <option>Option 1</option>
                    <option>2</option>
                    <option>3</option>
                    <option>4</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usr" placeholder="Placeholder">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Default</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Success</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Demo here : https://jsfiddle.net/adb0br5e/1/